# Field seems to be missing in some responses in Active Collab 4 API

Tags: api, activecollab

I am looking for fields in task called `is_completed` and `completed_on`.

When I do the `/projects/#PROJECT-ID#/tasks` API call I see `is_completed` but I do not see `completed_on`.

We are using the Cloud based version of Active Collab 4.

Any reason why I am not seeing `completed_on`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. You need to show some code and the things you have tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @bobg: Please provide more info: which version of Active Collab are you connecting to (that info is availalbe in Admin section of the app), and how (code sample that you are using to make the request).

Comment: Good Day Ilija, We are using the cloud version. I don't get a version setting under administration. We are using the API call for TASKs and having it displayed using the product KlipFolio. I can attach:

Comment: https://isowcs.manageprojects.com/api.php?path_info=projects/{props.projectID}/tasks&auth_api_token=166

Answer (score 0):

In Active Collab 4, there is a difference between "brief" API responses (used when returning large lists of objects), and detailed responses (used when a single object is returned via API).

When you are listing a list of tasks, you will get all individual tasks in brief format, but when you fetch details of each task, you'll get a detailed response.

In brief task responses, `completed_on` timestamp is not included, only whether tasks is completed or not (`is_completed`). To get the timestamp of completed tasks, make an additional call to task API for each task that is completed:

https://activecollab.com/help-classic/books/api/tasks#s-task-id

PS: In Active Collab 5, we removed brief and detailed concept, so each object always returns a single set of properties.